# Currently accepted cookie-less way to handle client-side session information in browser window?

Tags: jquery, dom, javascript, session-state

I have looked at the follow libraries/plugins, but some are a little older and I'm trying to determine if there is an accepted technique which people are generally using.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-session-variable-library/

http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

http://code.google.com/p/javascript-session-jss/

http://code.google.com/p/cometdim/source/browse/trunk/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.session.js?r=2

http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/javascript-session-variables-without-cookies/

http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

Comment: added one from http://stackoverflow.com/a/8499237/18255

Answer (score 1):

It's worth giving this guy a look.

http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

It provides a consistent API that will use HTML5 storage if available and fallback on a variety of other implementations when required.

Comment: Yep, I had that one too - are people converging on one library or plugin?